# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'flags')

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint, angular15, angular-upgrade

I am facing an error with **Angular 15.2.9** version:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'flags')
```

[image: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'flags')]

**ng v:**

[image: ng v]

I tried all the answers which are for Angular 9, but no luck.

**karma.conf.js**

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-typescript'),
      require('karma-spec-reporter'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-firefox-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    specReporter: {
      maxLogLines: 5,
      suppressErrorSummary: false,
      suppressFailed: false,
      suppressPassed: false,
      suppressSkipped: false,
      showSpecTiming: false,
      failFast: false,
    },
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' },
        { type: 'lcovonly' },
      ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
      check: {
        global: {
          statements: 50,
          branches: 15,
          functions: 45,
          lines: 50,
        },
      },
    },
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    browserDisconnectTimeout: 60000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
    browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
    reporters: ['spec', 'progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: '../../../../test-reports/angular/', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
      outputFile: undefined, // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
      suite: '', // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
      useBrowserName: true, // add browser name to report and classes names
      nameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the name attribute in xml testcase element
      classNameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the classname attribute in xml testcase element
      properties: {}, // key value pair of properties to add to the <properties> section of the report
      xmlVersion: null, // use '1' if reporting to be per SonarQube 6.2 XML format
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.ERROR,
    browsers: ['CustomChromeHeadless'],
    customLaunchers: {
      CustomChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox'],
      },
    },
  });
};
```

**.spec file:**

```
import {ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SuperSpecialityPageComponent } from './super-speciality-page.component';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { SuperSpecialtyPageService } from '@pages/super-speciality-page/services/super-specialty-page.service';
import { SuperSpecialtyPage, SuperSpecialty } from '@entities/content-types/SuperSpecialty';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {ISuperSpecialtyPageResponse} from '@interfaces/content-types/ISuperSpecialtyPageResponse';
import {JsonaService} from '@services/jsona.service';
import { JsonaHtml, IJsonaHtmlResponse } from '@pages/link-landing-page/domain/JsonaHtml';
import { HealthWellnessArticlesPage } from '@entities/content-types/HealthWellnessArticlesPage';
import { AwardsSection } from '@entities/AwardsSection';
import { ConditionFinder } from '@entities/paragraphs/ConditionFinder';
import { DrupalLink } from '@entities/fields/DrupalLink';
import { CallToActionSection } from '@entities/CallToAction';
import { DepartmentHistory } from '@entities/paragraphs/DepartmentHistory';
import { FeaturedContent } from '@entities/paragraphs/FeaturedContent';
import { Icon } from '@entities/paragraphs/Icon';
import { PatientStory } from '@entities/paragraphs/PatientStory';
import { Programs } from '@entities/paragraphs/Programs';
import { SliderContent } from '@entities/paragraphs/SliderContent';
import { SuperSpecialtyNavigation } from '@entities/paragraphs/SuperSpecialtyNavigation';
import { SspSubspecialty } from '@entities/paragraphs/SspSubspecialties';
import { ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
import { IArticleRecipeSearchPage } from '@interfaces/content-types/IArticleRecipeSearchPage';

describe('SuperSpecialityPageComponent', () => {
  let component: SuperSpecialityPageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SuperSpecialityPageComponent>;
  const sspSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj<SuperSpecialtyPageService>('SuperSpecialtyPageService', ['getSuperSpecialtyPage']);

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        CommonModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        SuperSpecialityPageComponent
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
          snapshot: {
            data: {
              'data': of({
                isRevision: false,
                entity: {
                  id: '1'
                },
                jsonapi: {
                  individual: '/jsonapi/node/super_specialty/4f0222fb-19eb-4aeb-935c-9ddfc91ba73c?include=field_awards.field_icon_image,field_condition_finder,field_ssp_cta,field_department_history.field_decades.field_years.field_timeline_media.field_image,field_department_history.field_decades.field_years.field_timeline_media.field_youtube_thumbnail,field_featured_content_items.field_image,field_icons.field_icon_image,field_leadership_practice_card,field_patient_stories.field_image,field_ssp_programs.field_ssp_program_card.field_image,field_ssp_hero_slider.field_cta_options,field_ssp_hero_slider.field_image,field_ssp_hero_slider.field_mobile_image,field_sub_navigation,field_sub_specialties.field_media.field_image,field_sub_specialties.field_sub_specialties&fields[file--file]=url,uri'
                }
              })
            }
          }
        }},
        { provide: SuperSpecialtyPageService, useValue: sspSpy }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    const appRef = TestBed.inject(ApplicationRef) as ApplicationRef;
    const mockResponse = require('@pages/super-speciality-page/mocks/MockSuperSpecialtyPageResponse1.json');
    const MockSuperSpecialtyPageResponse: ISuperSpecialtyPageResponse = JsonaService.deserializeMockResponse(mockResponse);
    sspSpy.getSuperSpecialtyPage.and.returnValue(of(new SuperSpecialtyPage(MockSuperSpecialtyPageResponse)));
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SuperSpecialityPageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    appRef.components.push(fixture.componentRef);
    component.content$ = mockResponse;
    component.content$.sspCateogory = {
      'drupal_internal__tid' : 12345,
      'name' : 'Health at every Age'
    };
    component.content$.relatedArticles = [
      {
        title : 'Article 1'
      },
      {
        title : 'Article 2'
      },
      {
        title : 'Article 3'
      },
      {
        title : 'Article 4'
      },
      {
        title : 'Article 5'
      },
      {
        title : 'Article 6'
      },
    ];
    component.content$.relatedArticles.length = 5;
    component.cardsToBeDisplay = 5;
    component.content$.overwriteArticlesID = [12345, 87368, 23947, 34902, 34343];
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should call ngoninit again', () => {
    const mockResponse = require('@pages/super-speciality-page/mocks/MockSuperSpecialtyPageResponse1.json');
    const MockSuperSpecialtyPageResponse: ISuperSpecialtyPageResponse = JsonaService.deserializeMockResponse(mockResponse);
    sspSpy.getSuperSpecialtyPage.and.returnValue(of(new SuperSpecialtyPage(MockSuperSpecialtyPageResponse)));
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SuperSpecialityPageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.content$ = mockResponse;
    component.content$.relatedArticles = [];
    component.content$.relatedArticles.length = 0;
    component.cardsToBeDisplay = 5;
    component.content$.overwriteArticlesID = [12345, 87368, 23947, 34902, 34343];
    component.content$.sspCateogory = {
      'drupal_internal__tid' : 12345,
      'name' : 'Health at every Age'
    };
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should call ngoninit for no sspCategory', () => {
    const mockResponse = require('@pages/super-speciality-page/mocks/MockSuperSpecialtyPageResponse1.json');
    const MockSuperSpecialtyPageResponse: ISuperSpecialtyPageResponse = JsonaService.deserializeMockResponse(mockResponse);
    sspSpy.getSuperSpecialtyPage.and.returnValue(of(new SuperSpecialtyPage(MockSuperSpecialtyPageResponse)));
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SuperSpecialityPageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.content$ = mockResponse;
    component.content$.relatedArticles = [
      {
        title : 'Article 1'
      },
      {
        title : 'Article 2'
      },
      {
        title : 'Article 3'
      },
    ];
    component.content$.relatedArticles.length = 4;
    component.cardsToBeDisplay = 5;
    component.content$.overwriteArticlesID = [12345, 87368, 23947, 34902, 34343];
    component.content$.sspCateogory = {};
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should call getRedirectURL', () => {
    component.redirectURL = '/search/health-and-wellness';
    component.getRedirectURL();
    expect(component.getRedirectURL).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call getRedirectURL empty', () => {
    component.redirectURL = '/';
    component.getRedirectURL();
    expect(component.getRedirectURL).toBeTruthy();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call setSspActiveTab', () => {
    component.sspActiveTab = 'department-history';
    component.setSspActiveTab('department-history');
    expect(component.setSspActiveTab).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call setSspActiveTab', () => {
    component.sspActiveTab = 'home';
    component.setSspActiveTab('department-history');
    expect(component.setSspActiveTab).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call constantCard', () => {
    component.content$.relatedArticles = [{}];
    component.constantCard('123', 'abc', true);
    expect(component.constantCard).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you post the spec contents to check?

Comment: @Jai updated the question with `.spec` file

Comment: Where is this `flags` property is used? I think you have to mock it up in `beforeEach` block.

Comment: @Jai I have not used that property anywhere!